# SQLAlchemy filter by dict of lists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Trying to make a query in flask_sqlalchemy. I want to filter using a dict of lists and using ORM not a query string.
Still new to SQLAlchemy so any help would be appreciated.

I know I can do:

```
filter = {
'name': 'apple'
, 'age': 14
}

Items.query.filter(**filter).all()
```

Which translates to:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = 'apple' AND age = 14;
```

---

But I want:

```
filter = {
'name': ['apple', 'pear']
, 'age': [14, 15, 21]
}
```

To be:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE name IN ('apple', 'pear') AND age IN (14, 15, 21);
```

Comment: Most likely you will need to implement own "translator" from `dict` to filters. In general, you need to specify the `operation` in addition to `key` and `values`, which could be `IN`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, etc... I am not aware of out-of-the-box implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
filter = {
    'name': ['apple', 'pear']
    , 'age': [14, 15, 21]
}    

items = Item.query

for field in query:
    items = items.filter(getattr(Item, field).in_(query[field]))

items = items.all()
```